# Get substring from string in Liquid?

Tags: function, substring, jekyll, liquid

I am working with Jekyll and I have the string `balh blah blah&garbage **&*&% garbage <h1>TITLE</h1> &^*$%"`

Is there a way to grab TITLE? I have looked at the functions [here](http://cheat.markdunkley.com/) but I don't see something that I can use.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`split` to the rescue !

```
{% assign str = 'garbage <h1>TITLE</h1> moregarbage' %}
{% assign a = str | split: '<h1>' %}
```

We now have `garbage` in a[0] and `TITLE</h1> moregarbage` in a[1]

```
{% assign b = a[1] | split: '</h1>' %}
```

We now have `TITLE` in b[0] and `moregarbage` in b[1]

Comment: Actually I came up with that just when you were typing your answer :) It's sad they don't allow wildcards. This is usable but it's rather prone to break if h1 has a class for example.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is ancient, but for anyone else coming across it: https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/operators/

> contains contains checks for the presence of a substring inside a
>   string.
>
> {% if product.title contains "Pack" %}   This product's title contains
>   the word Pack. {% endif %}
>
> contains can also check for the presence of a string in an array of
>   strings.
>
> {% if product.tags contains "Hello" %}   This product has been tagged
>   with "Hello". {% endif %}
>
> contains can only search strings. You cannot use it to check for an
>   object in an array of objects.

Comment: This worked best for me in this case. I was able to add a special class to elements with the same word in the product title.